# excluding SecurityAutoConfiguration does not disable spring security basic authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am simply trying to disable spring security and later on add it based on a condition from my properties file but the basic spring security is not getting disabled. I am using spring security `2.2.4.RELEASE` with spring boot starter `2.2.4.RELEASE`
Below is my code.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to exclude other classes. If you are using `spring-boot-starter-actuator`, you also need to exclude `ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class`.